# Preview SMS format when sending email to SMS

Tags: email, sms

I'm using carrier-specific addresses to send email to SMS, which works fine. In reference to the answer of this question [Limitations on SMS messages sent using free email->SMS gateways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179854/limitations-on-sms-messages-sent-using-free-email-sms-gateways) is there any websites or other resources that list the format that is delivered for each carrier. ATT for example delivers the SMS with some added formatting that is not present with T-Mobile.

I realize this is not a coding question, but since I can only see this question arising for someone that is creating email to SMS specific applications, it seems relevant to SO.

Answer (score 1):

I spend *a lot* of time working with SMS (I work at Twilio)  and I don't know of such a thing, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Maybe a wiki for reporting the formatting differences would be useful?

Comment: This is an opinion I formed prior to working at Twilio, but I can see how this sounds bias: I wouldn't bother with email to SMS gateways. It's a horrible user experience (inconsistent end user results like you describe), unreliable (delivery is slower and carrier spam filters more agressive), error prone (most notably when users switch carriers). I know free is very enticing but your time is worth money too. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has some information on formatting, though its kind of unclear and possibly inaccurate:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateways

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_SMS_transit