# Testing Email to SMS

Tags: sms

I recently found out that you can send an email to a mobile number (e.g: [number]@[provider].com) for free in a lot of countries which is cool!

Unfortunately I live in Australia and my mobile provider doesn't allow free Email to SMS so I can't test it at present.

Has anyone worked with this sort of thing before? In an email there is a subject and a message. Do both of these get translated into the SMS or is it just the subject or message?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for most carriers in Canada and USA that I have tested. Subject isn't passed, only the message and on some carriers / phones the "Sender" shows the email it came from and on others it just shows a random string of characters.   Usually this makes replying not possible as well as telling where the message came from.

Comment: This has been my experience as well. Delivery is not 100% guaranteed either, but given that email is basically free, it's not a bad solution for certain kinds of notifications.

Comment: You mentioned "Usually this makes replying not possible as well as telling where the message came from"... the times it is possible, does the reply go back to the email address?

Comment: With my experiences, at first I thought it was dependant on the data sent to the mobile phone by the telco. But after testing with a few different devices on the same network, it appeared to be related to the phone. My old Samsung M600 would receive an incoming "email" and format the sender as a random 8-digit string. Message being the message (Up to 160 characters only, rest would get cut ofF).  Whereas on a friends Nokia, the email would be shown and a reply was possible from his phone.  It's a hit-or-miss issue, everything is kind of out of your control.  Hopefully it works for your needs.

Comment: Hi Mike, I know a company that seems to allow replies from SMS messages back to their software. I'd like to look more into this. Would you have any idea where I could go to get answers?

Comment: That one I'm not really sure where to even start.  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

For me (on AT&T) the subject is preserved. The iPhone will actually display it with a linebreak, though in older versions it used to have

```
Subject: Hello
Message: This is a test SMS.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely one of the more interesting things carriers support. Another drawback, however, is that you need to know which carrier a number you're sending SMS to belongs to, let alone controlling the format of a text message.

The limitations are well described: [Limitations on SMS messages sent using free email->SMS gateways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179854/limitations-on-sms-messages-sent-using-free-email-sms-gateways)

If you use a third-party SMS gateway provider, you may be able to bypass the carrier lookup issue and have more flexibility. (e.g., [Email and SMS gateway using Plivo and Mailgun API](https://plivo.com/docs/getting-started/sms-to-email-gateway-integration/)). I work at Plivo.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, carriers in most countries outside the USA and Canada either don't have an email-to-sms gateway, or the gateways are unreliable.  I'm not sure why this is, but my guess is that in the USA and Canada, texting is typically paid for by both the senders and the recipients of the messages, whereas in other countries it is only paid for by the senders. By using the email-to-sms gateways, at least carriers in the USA are getting paid by the recipients. But in other countries they aren't getting paid at all.

At least that was the case ten or fifteen years ago. But now most phone subscribers in the USA and Canada pay for unlimited plans, so they really aren't getting additional revenue for these messages.

So maybe the real reason they work in the USA and Canada is that it USED to be profitable for them, and now people in these countries expect these gateways to work, because they always have.